# Is there a word for opposite numbers?

Tags: word-choice, terminology, numbers, mathematics

Example: -100 and +100 - is there a way of describing the relationship between these numbers?

Obviously, I've already come up with "opposite", is there anything else?

This is for use in an email.

Example usage:

There's an issue with records that contain values that are opposite values of each other, -100 and +100

Comment: -100 is the negative of +100.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's called the [*additive inverse*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_inverse).

In a less technical context, you could just call them *negatives* of each other.

Similarly, `5` and `1/5` are [*multiplicative inverses*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_inverse).

Comment: Wow. I think I'll stick with "opposite" for this email then.

Comment: I thought you were looking for the technical term. If it's casual email, try _negative_.

Comment: Thanks. How would you phrase it though? "There's an issue with records that are negatives of each other"?

Comment: Yes, something like that would be fine. If you said _opposites_, I'm not sure they would understand that you refer to the number values.

Comment: Agreed, that's why I asked. Negatives makes much more sense.

Comment: `5` and `1/5` are also commonly called reciprocals, although that's not as precise.

Answer (score 5):

This is hardly mainstream English, but there is a term.

The identity element under addition for the set of reals (or the set of integers)  is zero;

x + 0 = 0 + x = x

The element that must be added to any element to give the identity element as the  product (the general term for result of a binary operation; here the sum) is, for addition, known as the **additive inverse** of that element (number).

Comment: Is there a better place for this type of question since it's not mainstream?

Comment: The domain involved is maths, so the relevant SE website, or most other maths websites.

Comment: Good to know - thanks. I probably should've elaborated on my intent though.

Answer (score 3):

As noted by Barmar, additive inverse is the technically correct term, but in your context, you could use the following phrase:

> There's an issue with records that contain values that **differ only in their sign**. For example, -100 and +100.

You could also say:

> There's an issue with records that contain values that **have equal magnitude but opposite sign**. For example, -100 and +100.

I have read both these in various textbooks written by American authors. You could pick one of these alternatives, or a similar variant, depending on your audience.